# Quadrocopter Ardrone detection and tracking QRCode

Tags: ros, tracking, ardrone

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm now using a `visp_auto_tracker` package to detect QR-code for Quadrocopter, but during flying it can not work because of the vibration of Quadrocopter, how can I solve this problem? The aim is to detect it and use the relative position to fly stably and get the info from QR-code.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/225436/quadrocopter-ardrone-detection-and-tracking-qrcode/) by [Eric_0987](https://answers.ros.org/users/25789/eric_0987/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2016-01-30

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Based on my prior experience, [ar_track_alvar](http://wiki.ros.org/ar_track_alvar) can robustly detect and track QR like tags on AR-Drone 2.0 video feed when the drone is hovering or slowly moving. Parrot Bebop Drone's (the successor to AR-Drone 2.0) video stream is quite stable since it performs on-board video stabilization. You may be able to use `visp_auto_tracker` with Bebop.

---

Originally posted by [Mani](https://answers.ros.org/users/1858/mani/) with karma: 1704 on 2016-02-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1